# How to get youTube broadcasted-video URL using youTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, broadcast

Is it possible to get youTube **broadcasted-video** URL using **youTube API**?
As I realized, broadcasted video URL **changes** everytime broadcasting is **restarted**. 
I want to get new URL **programmatically**, and show broadcast-video in iFrame in my website.
Are all these possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer is very easy:
From Youtube Data API documentation I've found the method where I can fetch all videos by author:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=crystalspringllc

And there is a video URL I want.